# Poor performance when combining join and where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a problem when joining 2 tables AND using a date in my where clause.
Query #1 takes ages to run
Query #2 runs fine (no join)
Query #3 runs fine (no where clause)

Code

```
Query 1 
    select    t1.id 
    from      t1
    inner     join t2
    on        t1.id = t2.inst_id
    where     t1.change_date >= to_date('04-06-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    ; -- does not work

Query 2
    select    t1.id 
    from      t1
    --inner     join t2
    --on        t1.id = t2.inst_id
    where     t1.change_date >= to_date('04-06-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    ; -- work in < 1s


Query 3 
    select    t1.id 
    from      t1
    inner     join t2
    on        t1.id = t2.inst_id
    --where     t1.change_date >= to_date('04-06-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    ; -- works in < 1s
```

Do you know why the combination of the join and the where clause with a date is problematic ?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what indexes you might have on the tables, or how many rows of data are in each.

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean? Do you have records that match both of those conditions (where t1 and t2 share an `id` and `inst_id` respectively AND `t1.change_date` is greater than `04-06-2018`? Please share some sample data and your desired results.

Comment: It changes the execution plan.  It is also possible that you are looking at when the *first* row is being returned, but the query with the `join` needs to process more data before it returns anything.

Comment: Assuming the reason why Query 2 is fast is because of an index on the date column, I would suggest you find out (via explain plan) what index Query 2 uses and then add a hint in Query 1 to use that ... and then pray ...

Answer (score -1):

Without your table structures/indexes/statistics I could only propose to check:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT /*+materialize*/ t1.id  
  FROM t1
  WHERE t1.change_date >= to_date('04-06-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
)
SELECT *
FROM cte c
JOIN t2
  ON c.id = t2.inst_id;
```

---

**EDIT**:

More correct approach is to add extended statistics:

```
select  dbms_stats.create_extended_stats(null,'t1','(id, change_date)')
from dual;
```

Comment: I dont think its a good idea, as you are materialising a query involving a date constant '04-06-2018', which will clearly change between queries.

Comment: @Peeyush This is idea to check. Anyway we don't really know how OP passes argument, real query or how many times it will run (it may be some OLTP workload or some report query which runs once a quarter).

Comment: I understand for OLTP its definitely not good, but even for OLAP workload, this will only work if the selectivity of where is sufficiently small, so that using secondary index based range scan on t1.change_date is more costly.

Comment: @Peeyush Sure, probably more realistic approach is to add extended_stats